# create list column by mapping over data columns and pattern rows

Tags: r, purrr

**The overarching problem:**

I have my data tibble,

```
dat <- tibble(var1 = c("rnw wnd", "rnw wat"),
              var2 = c("elc", NA))
```

I have another dataset which is a set of rules for pattern matching, such that if var1, var2 with combine_rule == T, the grp is assigned.

```
patterns <- tibble(var1_patterns = c("rnw", "wnd", NA),
                   var2_patterns = c("elc", NA, "elc"),
                   combine_rule = c("&", NA, NA),
                   grp = c("elc_rnw", "wnd", "elc"))
```

I would like to append a list column to `dat` that contains all the grps that the var1, var2 combination satisfy the rules for.

So the result would be:

```
dat <- tibble(var1 = c("rnw wnd", "rnw wat"),
              var2 = c("elc", NA), 
              grp = c(list(c("elc_rnw", "wnd", "elc")),
                      list(NA))
)
```

**Simpler problem**

That is the full problem, which I realise is quite a lot. In the first instance,  it would be helpful to get input into how I map str_match(var1, var1_pattern) to create a list column ignoring the logical relation between var1 and var2. So the result would be:

```
dat <- tibble(var1 = c("rnw wnd", "rnw wat"),
              var2 = c("elc", NA), 
              grp = c(list( c("elc_rnw", "wnd")), 
                      list("elc_rnw"))
)
```

I thought of something like mapping `str_match`,

```
dat %>%
     mutate(grp = map(var1, ~str_match(.x, pattern$var1_pattern))
```

to create a new list column. But I do not know how to map over rows of `pattern` to create a list column. There is a loop option, but I am trying my best to avoid that!

I should also add, that `pattern` and `dat` will be arguments to a function, so I (think that I) cannot use case_when for pattern matching.

Any suggestions for either the simple problem, or overarching problem would be much appreciated.

(Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I have not found questions, perhaps because I have not phrased the question appropriately)

Comment: Thanks. That should now be fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have found a solution for the overaching problem for the specific  case of the logical "&" in pattern.

If someone has suggestions for a more elegant way of going about this, or any other suggestions, they would be most welcome.

```
# Create dat and patterns
dat <- tibble::tibble(var1 = c("rnw wnd", "rnw wat"),
              var2 = c("elc", NA))

patterns <- tibble::tibble(var1_patterns = c("rnw", "wnd", NA),
                   var2_patterns = c("elc", NA, "elc"),
                   combine_rule = c("&", NA, NA),
                   grp = c("elc_rnw", "wnd", "elc"))
    
# function to return logical matches if pattern detected
check_for_matches <- function(var, patterns){

  out <- stringr::str_detect(var, patterns)
  # if var is missing, we want to return F for all matches
  if(is.na(var)){
    out <- replace(out, 1:length(out), F)
    }
  out

}


dat %>%
  #create logicals for detection of var1 and var2 seperately
  dplyr::mutate(var1_check = purrr::map(var1,
                                ~check_for_matches(.x,
                                                   patterns$var1_patterns))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(var2_check = purrr::map(var2,
                                  ~check_for_matches(.x,
                                                     patterns$var2_patterns))) %>%
  #append the group column
  dplyr::mutate(grp = list(patterns$grp)) %>%
  # unnest because we are working across columns 
  tidyr::unnest(c(var1_check, var2_check, grp)) %>%
  #create logical for joining var1_check and var2_check and accounting for NAs
  dplyr::mutate(joined = dplyr::if_else(is.na(var1_check & var2_check) == F,
                                        var1_check & var2_check,
                                        dplyr::if_else(is.na(var1_check), var2_check,
                                                       var1_check)),
                # if joined T, then grp
                grp = dplyr::if_else(joined, grp, NA_character_)) %>%
  dplyr::select(var1, var2, grp) %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = c(grp))
```